# Query Managed Metadata Service in Content by Search WebPart

Tags: 2013, web-part, managed-metadata, term-store

I have created a site navigation structure in SharePoint Managed Metadata Service and I add a custom property to each term.

How can I query the Managed Metadata Service by the Content Search WebPart and how can I filter it by the term's custom property?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use the term in sharepoint list/library item to get it crawled. Content search web part can pick it up once the term is crawled !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is possible to configure the Content Search Web Part to use the custom properties within a term.

Something you could try is to add some script to the page to get the value of the custom property and place it in a text field and then configure the Content Search Web Part to read the value from the text box as part of the query.